# ASP.NET - Read Component Parameter In Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an existing ASP.NET app that uses one Razor component throughout. Unfortunately, this component does *not* have a model associated with it. I'm in a scenario where I need to add one parameter. At this time, I have the following in the component host view:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("MyTextField", new { Align = "Left" })
```

The component Razor code currently looks like this:

**MyTextField.cshtml**

```
<div class="text-right">
  <form asp-action="ReadItem" asp-controller="Inventory" method="get" id="inventory-form">
    <input id="inputField" class="input-text" type="text" />
    <button class="submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Currently, the component renders. However, I want to get the value of the `Align` parameter, if it exists, in the `MyTextField.cshtml` view. Is there a way for me to get a parameter value there? If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in this way:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("MyTextField", new User{ Align = "Left" })
```

and in View (cshtml file):

```
@using UserNamespace
@model User

<div class="text-right">
  <form asp-action="ReadItem" asp-controller="Inventory" method="get" id="inventory-form">
    <input id="inputField" class="input-text" type="text" value="@Model.Align" />
    <button class="submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without a model? In other words, is there a way to read properties from an anonymous type in a razor file?

Comment: It is a bad practice to do that but I think it is possible. Maybe you can create an object (Model) with dynamic property which can be a class or numeric type. ViewBag for example is dynamic, I think in same way you can do that with @model.  But if you use .net core why you not use ViewComponent, I think it is better chois